I cant implement AJAX in my django forum app to post a question
I have a forum app in which users can post their questions. I want to prevent page reloading each time a user post a comment for a question. I've tried implementing ajax but it didn't work.
I've done this:
this is forms.py:
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # add a "form-control" class to each form input
        # for enabling bootstrap
        for name in self.fields.keys():
            self.fields[name].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control',
            })

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('question', 'reply_to', 'text')

this is views.py:
def post_comment(request):
    # request should be ajax and method should be POST.
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        # get the form data
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        # save the data and after fetch the object in instance
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            # serialize in new friend object in json
            ser_instance = serializers.serialize('json', [instance, ])
            # send to client side.
            return JsonResponse({"instance": ser_instance}, status=200)
        else:
            # some form errors occured.
            return JsonResponse({"error": form.errors}, status=400)

    # some error occured
    return JsonResponse({"error": ""}, status=400)

this is urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path('comment/', post_comment, name='post-comment'),

]

this is base.html:
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    {% block javascript %}
    {% endblock javascript %}

this is index.html:
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="comment-form">
        <div class="row">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label class="col-12">{{ field.label }}</label>
                {{ field }}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create comment" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<hr />

{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
<script>
    $("#comment-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{% url 'post-comment' %}",
            data: serializedData,
            success: function (response) {
                // on successfull creating object
                // 1. clear the form.
                $("#comment-form").trigger('reset');

            },
            error: function (response) {
                // alert the error if any error occured
                alert(response["responseJSON"]["error"]);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
{% endblock javascript %}

Something must be wrong with my device because I've tried this with many tutorials and still I couldnt make it. once I cloned a rep and it didn't work.

The is_ajax method on requests was removed in Django 4.0 are you using a version lower than that?

Corrections
1. In base.html, setup code as this:
   {% block content %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% block javascript %}
   {% endblock%}

   <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        //DOM loaded
        {% block domready %}
        {% endblock %}
    })
   </script>

2. In index.html, setup code as this:
   And judging from the code snippet, **index.html** extends **base.html**, therefore it needs to be loaded in **index.html** as well
  
   {% extends "base.html" %}
   {% block content %}
     //code stub here
   {% endblock %}

   {% block javascript %}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   {% endblock%}

   {% block domready %}
    //ajax code stub here
   {% endblock %}

 
  [POINTS TO NOTE]

  The block named {% block javascript %} will allow you to insert JavaScript files in any template that extends the base.html template.
 
  You add JavaScript code to the {% block domready %} block that was defined in 
  the event listener for the **DOMContentLoaded event** in the **base.xhtml** template. 
  This guarantees that your JavaScript code will be executed **once the page has been loaded.** 

  [Source: Django by Example - Antonio Mele]

